# How to check if a cell of type integer array contains a certain value in SQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm using postgresql. How can I check if a cell (type integer[]) contains a certain value?
There is a cell (row_of_type_integer_array) is a row of type integer[].
There is one cell containing the values {2, 3, 4}

Now I want sth like: if there is a cell containg the value 2 (not only 2, but also 2), then return sth. This would be the case in the given cell mentioned above.

I tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE row_of_type_integer_array = 2;
```

However this isn't working. I also tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE 2 IN row_of_type_integer_array;
```

But this isn't working either. Which way can I go else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do it. Here's one:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 2 = ANY(row_of_type_integer_array)
```