# SELECT * where all of integer[] cell are in a set of values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-in

I'm trying to solve exactly this: [How to check if a cell of type integer array contains a certain value in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670087/how-to-check-if-a-cell-of-type-integer-array-contains-a-certain-value-in-sql)
but for multiple values on boths sides

so something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE ALL(column_of_type_integer_array) IN (2,3,4)
```

Is there anything like this or do I have to split my values up?

### Edit:

table **callenges**

```
id| precoditions
-----------------
1 |[]
2 |[]
3 |[]
4 |[2,3]
```

So I only want to select chalenges where the precodition challenges are fullfilled.

```
SELECT id FROM callenges WHERE All(preconditions) IN ${solvedChallenges}
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help us understand your question better.

Comment: @GMB done, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the operator `<@` - [is contained by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(arr) as (
values
    (array[2,3,4,2,3]),
    (array[1,2,3,4,2,3])
)

select *
from my_table
where arr <@ array[2,3,4]

     arr     
-------------
 {2,3,4,2,3}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a solution without some kind of splitting, but you do not need to repeat some parts of your query. I would split up the array using `unnest()`:

```sql
SELECT m.id
FROM mytable m
WHERE (SELECT bool_and(u.i IN (2, 3, 4)) FROM unnest(m.int_array) u (i))
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for unset in combination with SQL do you have any reference?

Comment: Since you tagged PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: And please note, the function is called ```unnest``` and NOT ```unset```.